# Node clones not maintaining geometry despite copying it over in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a little painting app in SceneKit that I originally developed on iOS 9. There's a part where I take a collection of nodes, clone them, then flatten them to make one single node that can be moved around.

Problem is, in iOS 9 I was able to successfully do the "deep clone" technique where I copy over the node's geometry and materials, and these properties were retained. This is not the case in iOS 12, however. The geometry gets all wonky despite running the exact same code. I've spent a few hours trying different variations of the process below, to no avail. Here's the code:

```
func sendPainting() {
        // a parent node that contains the canvas and frame nodes as children
        guard let configPainting = sceneView.scene!["configpainting"] else {
            return
        }

        guard let configCanvas = configPainting.childNode(withName: "canvas", recursively: true) else {
            return
        }

        guard let configFrame = configPainting.childNode(withName: "frame", recursively: true) else {
            return
        }

        let configClone = configPainting.clone()

        // copy over geometry and material      
        configClone.childNode(withName: "canvas", recursively: true)?.geometry = configCanvas.geometry?.copy() as? SCNGeometry
        configClone.childNode(withName: "canvas", recursively: true)?.geometry?.firstMaterial = configCanvas.geometry?.firstMaterial?.copy() as? SCNMaterial
        configClone.childNode(withName: "frame", recursively: true)?.geometry = configFrame.geometry?.copy() as? SCNGeometry
        configClone.childNode(withName: "frame", recursively: true)?.geometry?.firstMaterial = configFrame.geometry?.firstMaterial?.copy() as? SCNMaterial

        // make a flattened clone to now have the canvas and frame consolidated into 1 node
        let localClone = configClone.flattenedClone()

...

        // add to my scene
        sceneView.scene!["localpaintings"]?.addChildNode(localClone)
}
```

Here's what the group of nodes look like before cloning and flattening, in both iOS 9 and 12:

[image: before]

And after:

In iOS 9, geometry is retained (sorry, different image, but you get the idea):

[image: ios9]

In iOS 12, the frame gets shrunk and rotated:

[image: ios12]

Comment: That's a SceneKit bug that happens since iOS 11 I think, some `transform` and `pivot` properties are not retained when doing a flattened clone. Is there any reason why you need to flatten the hierarchy?

Comment: @jlsiewert I flatten them because once they are in that new scene, I want to be able to move them around (gesture) as a unit, regardless of where the user touches. If you know a better way to achieve this and circumvent the bug I'm all ears

Comment: just put the entire hierarchy under a single parent node that you then move around.

Comment: @jlsiewert That's what I'm doing here, no? I'm making that parent node, `config painting`, and then adding the children nodes to it. If i just use `clone()` instead of `flattenClone()`, then my frame doesn't appear at all.

Comment: `clone()` should work as expected. Do you need to modify geometry or material data? If not, you don't need your custom copy logic